# Iterate over column to find if a value is in there? (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, iterated-function

In a column I want to iterate over say row 1-7 to see if it contains value A. If it contains value A I want to print value C. If FALSE I want to check say row 8 - 10,and if TRUE i want to print value D. If FALSE I want to continue to row 11 - 20, and if TRUE print value E and so on... See this link for clarification: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XHe1.jpg

[image]

[image]

I've tried using an IFS but when I do I get an error basically saying that the formula expected 21 rows but only got 11, the reason being the first time I iterate over the list it's checking 21 rows, and the next time it's 11, the time after that it might be 6 rows and so on. Any idea how to solve this issue?

Right now I've had do do each and every row manually which is insanely time consuming. Thanks.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: I may have a solution to this problem. However, Ayan, you have not checked in to review or even acknowledge the work done so far on your behalf by volunteer contributors here. So I'm hesitant to invest more work into this post if you've abandoned it or no longer want/need the help. If you are still interested, A.) check in and respond via comments; and B.) as player0 requested above, please share a link to your sample sheet (which will be far more helpful than an image, because we'll have starter data to test with).

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(E2; IF(A2:A="";; {A2:A\ 
 VLOOKUP(SORT(ROW(A2:A); 1; 0); IF(SORT(B2:B; ROW(A2:A); 0)<>""; 
 {ROW(A2:A)\ SORT(B2:B; ROW(A2:A); 0)}); 2; 1)}); 2; 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: On the heels of your comment to my reply post (which I've now deleted, because of factors you caused me to notice the second time around on the image), I'm now wondering if your formula will get accurate results either. It seems the color-coded sections in the OP's image are regular in one facet (i.e., the same number of blanks above and below each right-hand number considered as part of that section, starting from the top for that count), but irregular in how many rows above and below exist around each central number in the right-hand column.

Comment: @ErikTyler hmm, indeed, I missed that color too I guess.

Comment: I'm thinking that this may be one of the rare occasions where merging cells may actually *accomplish* a goal rather than inhibiting it. Merging the right-hand cells into one for each section would allow horizontal and vertical centering while clearly marking the beginning of each new section. But... we've asked for a shared sheet and haven't yet gotten one. I'll wait until when and if we do before I invest the additional time. Just thought I'd share my thinking.

Comment: I believe I've solved this problem, player0: purely via formula to ascertain the row groupings, no merging. But I'm waiting to see if the OP checks back in (since, IMO, volunteer contributors should never be investing more time and effort into keeping up with a post than the original poster is willing to invest).